# Script com IF (horário) menor que

Tags: ms-dos

Estou atrás de um comando (cmd/batch) para executar um comando com uma condição.

Ex: Checando o nome do usuario

```
 SET var=%username%
    IF "%var%"=="Carlos" (msg Carlos 'usuario confirmado')

    pause
```

Gostaria de outro para checar também o horário, para ser exibido a msg de bom dia, boa tarde, boa noite.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SET var= "Digite o usuário"
    IF %var%=="Carlos" Goto MSG

:MSG
 Echo "Carlos usuario confirmado"
    pause
```

E para a data teste isso:

```
echo %time:~0,2%

if %time:~0,2%  LEQ 12 goto manha
if %time:~0,2%  LEQ 18 goto tarde
if %time:~0,2%  LEQ 24 goto noite

:manha
    echo "manha"
    Pause

:tarde
    echo "tarde"
    Pause

:noite
    echo "noite"
    Pause
```

Comment: É isso. Funcionou?

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: sim ;) isso mesmo que queria

Comment: Não querendo abusar, mas como eu incluiria u tempo para madrugada? EX: de 00:00 até 06:00?

Comment: coloca mais um if

Comment: if %time:~0,2%  LEQ 6 goto madrugada

Comment: Vlw! Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Se puder da uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332063/inserir-vari%C3%A1vel-em-script