# Inserir variável em script

Tags: batch, ms-dos

Tenho o seguinte script funcionando normalmente

```
@echo off

if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 11:59:59 goto manha
if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 17:59:59 goto tarde
if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 23:59:59 goto noite

:manha
    echo "BOM DIA"
    Pause

:tarde
    echo "BOA TARDE"
    Pause

:noite
    echo "BOA NOITE"
    Pause
```

Gostaria de inserir uma variável para poder utilizar em outras linhas, Exemplo do codigo abaixo que não deu certo:

```
@echo off

if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 11:59:59 goto manha
if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 17:59:59 goto tarde
if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 23:59:59 goto noite



:manha
    set saudacao= "BOM DIA"


:tarde
    set saudacao= "BOA TARDE"


:noite
    set saudacao= "BOA NOITE"


echo %saudacao% , Resto da frase
pause
```

Alguem sabe no que estou errando?
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, neste segundo script falta colocar o `goto` após cada sentença:

Exemplo:

```
@echo off

if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 11:59:59 goto manha
if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 17:59:59 goto tarde
if %time:~0,8%  LEQ 23:59:59 goto noite

:manha
    set saudacao= "BOM DIA"
    goto fim


:tarde
    set saudacao= "BOA TARDE"
    goto fim
:noite
    set saudacao= "BOA NOITE"
    goto fim
:fim
   echo %saudacao% , Resto da frase
   pause
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez! :D

Comment: Por favor amigo finalize os dois itens e se puder me avalie. Abraços.

Comment: preciso de 15 de rep. para avaliar ;/ sorry